# how to store information at WCF server side

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which first ask client for login.

once client is logged in he can use other features as well.

now what i want? when client is successfully logged in , I want to store some of his information at WCF Service side.

I have created a perSession WCF service.

for example. every client has a client type. i want to store client type at service side. just like we store it in sessions in normal asp.net site.

I hope u understand what i want.

Comment: Anything that needs to be persisted between service calls belongs into a persistant store - e.g. a database. Put your SessionID plus your "client type" into a database table and read it as needed. WCF is **NOT** ASP.NET, it does **NOT** have a session state like ASP.NET (because that causes more grief than anything else....) and services should always be state-less

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF service operations should be state-less, i.e. the request contains everything that is required for the operation to execute.
What you are trying to implement is not a service-oriented architecture.

Comment: ok. but there is always a session between client and the service. there is always a state. i want to store these sessions at my service side. what could be the approach?when we are in Persession mode.

Comment: Please refer to the comment from @marc_s - your service should not persist session information itself, or it ceases to be atomic.